How can I get PyCharm to understand modules exist when their name is not identical to the package name?
In a Python project, I am using the graphql-core package.
I manage dependencies using Poetry, and have the Poetry interpreter assigned to the PyCharm project, with
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~3.10.0"
graphql-core = "^3.2.3"

listed in the pyproject.toml file.
This works fine for all other packages, but when I use
from graphql.validation import NoSchemaIntrospectionCustomRule

in a file, I get the warning

Package containing module 'graphql' is not listed in the project requirements

Since this is how the graphql-core package should be used according to its documentation, what do I need to do to make PyCharm understand this package does exist?
Of course, I could ignore the inspection in this project for this package, but I would prefer to understand how I can improve my setup to ensure PyCharm identifies such issues correctly.
I have also checked the packages listed in the interpreter settings, and graphql-core is listed as expected.Since this is how the graphql-core package should be used according to its documentation, what do I need to do to make PyCharm understand this package does exist?
